# Poisson distribution proof question

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I'm reading over the Poisson distribution proof and trying to understand how $$\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-\lambda)(n-\lambda)\cdots(n-\lambda)}$$ tends to 1 as $$n\rightarrow\infty\text{ ?}$$ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-a}{n-\lambda}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{a}{n}}{1-\frac{\lambda}{n}}
$$

and since 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n}=0
$$

we get that the above limit equals to $1$.

Finally, the limit in the question can be written as a product of
such limits (since all limits exists) and the limit is the product
of the limits and thus also equals to $1$.

Note: I assumed that the number of $n-\lambda$ expressions in the
denominator equals to$k$ which equals to the number of expressions
of the form $n-a$ in the numerator

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-\lambda)(n-\lambda)\cdots(n-\lambda)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{n}{n-\lambda}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n-\lambda}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-\lambda}\cdots\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n-\lambda}.
\end{align}

Each factor separately approaches $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: but how do we know that the number of terms in the denominator equals the number or terms in the numerator?

Comment: @YuriSwarovski : The expression you wrote, $\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-\lambda)(n-\lambda)\cdots(n-\lambda)}$, does not say how many factors are in the denominator, so that information has to come from somewhere other than what you wrote.  Presumably the logic of the proof you're reading should imply that there are $k$ factors in the denominators, just as in the numerator.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the proof and there is k terms in the denominator. Thanks.